# GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Using PostgreSQL 9.0.

Let's say I have a table containing the fields: `company`, `profession` and `year`. I want to return a result which contains unique companies and professions, but aggregates (into an array is fine) years based on numeric sequence:

Example Table:

```
+-----------------------------+
| company | profession | year |
+---------+------------+------+
| Google  | Programmer | 2000 |
| Google  | Sales      | 2000 |
| Google  | Sales      | 2001 |
| Google  | Sales      | 2002 |
| Google  | Sales      | 2004 |
| Mozilla | Sales      | 2002 |
+-----------------------------+
```

I'm interested in a query which would output rows similar to the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| company | profession | year             |
+---------+------------+------------------+
| Google  | Programmer | [2000]           |
| Google  | Sales      | [2000,2001,2002] |
| Google  | Sales      | [2004]           |
| Mozilla | Sales      | [2002]           |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

The essential feature is that only **consecutive years** shall be grouped together.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's much value to [@a_horse_with_no_name's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values/8015107#8015107), both as a correct solution and, like I already said in a comment, as a good material for learning how to use different kinds of window functions in PostgreSQL.

And yet I cannot help feeling that the approach taken in that answer is a bit too much of an effort for a problem like this one. Basically, what you need is an additional criterion for grouping before you go on aggregating years in arrays. You've already got `company` and `profession`, now you only need something to distinguish years that belong to different sequences.

That is just what the above mentioned answer provides and that is precisely what I think can be done in a simpler way. Here's how:

```
WITH MarkedForGrouping AS (
  SELECT
    company,
    profession,
    year,
    year - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY company, profession
      ORDER BY year
    ) AS seqID
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  company,
  profession,
  array_agg(year) AS years
FROM MarkedForGrouping
GROUP BY
  company,
  profession,
  seqID
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is the solution I in the long run, opted for using. It was for a single job which ran only periodically, so no need for a stored procedure. The code is clean, precise, and works as intended. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 26):

Identifying non-consecutive values is always a bit tricky and involves several nested sub-queries (at least I cannot come up with a better solution).

The first step is to identify non-consecutive values for the year:

#### Step 1) Identify non-consecutive values

```
select company, 
       profession,
       year,
       case 
          when row_number() over (partition by company, profession order by year) = 1 or 
               year - lag(year,1,year) over (partition by company, profession order by year) > 1 then 1
          else 0
       end as group_cnt
from qualification
```

This returns the following result:

```
 company | profession | year | group_cnt
---------+------------+------+-----------
 Google  | Programmer | 2000 |         1
 Google  | Sales      | 2000 |         1
 Google  | Sales      | 2001 |         0
 Google  | Sales      | 2002 |         0
 Google  | Sales      | 2004 |         1
 Mozilla | Sales      | 2002 |         1
```

Now with the group_cnt value we can create "group IDs" for each group that has consecutive years:

#### Step 2) Define group IDs

```
select company,
   profession,
   year,
   sum(group_cnt) over (order by company, profession, year) as group_nr
from ( 
select company, 
       profession,
       year,
       case 
          when row_number() over (partition by company, profession order by year) = 1 or 
               year - lag(year,1,year) over (partition by company, profession order by year) > 1 then 1
          else 0
       end as group_cnt
from qualification
) t1
```

This returns the following result:

```
 company | profession | year | group_nr
---------+------------+------+----------
 Google  | Programmer | 2000 |        1
 Google  | Sales      | 2000 |        2
 Google  | Sales      | 2001 |        2
 Google  | Sales      | 2002 |        2
 Google  | Sales      | 2004 |        3
 Mozilla | Sales      | 2002 |        4
(6 rows)
```

As you can see each "group" got its own group_nr and this we can finally use to aggregate over by adding yet another derived table:

#### Step 3) Final query

```
select company,
       profession,
       array_agg(year) as years
from (
  select company,
       profession,
       year,
       sum(group_cnt) over (order by company, profession, year) as group_nr
  from ( 
    select company, 
           profession,
           year,
           case 
              when row_number() over (partition by company, profession order by year) = 1 or 
                   year - lag(year,1,year) over (partition by company, profession order by year) > 1 then 1
              else 0
           end as group_cnt
    from qualification
  ) t1
) t2
group by company, profession, group_nr
order by company, profession, group_nr
```

This returns the following result:

```
 company | profession |      years
---------+------------+------------------
 Google  | Programmer | {2000}
 Google  | Sales      | {2000,2001,2002}
 Google  | Sales      | {2004}
 Mozilla | Sales      | {2002}
(4 rows)
```

Which is exactly what you wanted, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This absolutely 100% what I needed, and I very much appreciate all of the explanation and examples you've put into this!

Comment: Very descriptive, and I also like the fact how this solution uses window functions of three different kinds (`sum()`, `row_number()`, `lag()`), making it a good material on how to use them (combined in one solution too).

Answer (score 5):

#### Procedural solution with PL/pgSQL

The problem is rather unwieldy for plain SQL with aggregate / windows functions. While looping is typically slower than set-based solutions with plain SQL, a procedural solution with PL/pgSQL can make do with a **single sequential scan** over the table (implicit cursor of a `FOR` loop) and should be **substantially faster in this particular case**:

Test table:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (company text, profession text, year int);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  ('Google',  'Programmer', 2000)
, ('Google',  'Sales',      2000)
, ('Google',  'Sales',      2001)
, ('Google',  'Sales',      2002)
, ('Google',  'Sales',      2004)
, ('Mozilla', 'Sales',      2002)
;
```

Function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_periods()
  RETURNS TABLE (company text, profession text, years int[])
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r  tbl; -- use table type as row variable
   r0 tbl;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM tbl t ORDER BY t.company, t.profession, t.year
   LOOP
      IF ( r.company,  r.profession,  r.year)
      <> (r0.company, r0.profession, r0.year + 1) THEN -- not true for first row

         RETURN QUERY
         SELECT r0.company, r0.profession, years; -- output row

         years := ARRAY[r.year];     -- start new array
      ELSE
         years := years || r.year;   -- add to array - year can be NULL, too
      END IF;

      r0 := r;                       -- remember last row
   END LOOP;

   RETURN QUERY                      -- output last iteration
   SELECT r0.company, r0.profession, years;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_periods();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=64af9da0a41ac28a1ca984293e876763)*

Produces the requested result.

Comment: Slightly edited examples to give you better idea. Notice Google,Sales returns 2 results, the first containing the years 2000, 2001, 2002 because they are in sequential order while 2004 is a separate entry because there is no 2003 to create a complete sequence.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Nice solution and I agree that your version is probably a lot faster as it requires only a single scan over the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: though I have to admit that your version is an impressive demonstration of what window functions *can* do.