# Group by repeating attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, plpgsql, window-functions

Basically I have a table `messages`, with `user_id` field that identifies a user that created the message.

When I display a conversation(set of messages) between two users, I want to be able to group the messages by `user_id`, but in a tricky way:

Let's say there are some messages (sorted by `created_at desc`):

```
  id: 1, user_id: 1
  id: 2, user_id: 1
  id: 3, user_id: 2
  id: 4, user_id: 2
  id: 5, user_id: 1
```

I want to get 3 message groups in the below order:
`[1,2], [3,4], [5]`

It should group by *user_id* until it sees a different one and then groups by that one.

I'm using PostgreSQL and would be happy to use something specific to it, whatever would give the best performance.

Comment: I don't think you need a `GROUP BY` for this. It should be more an applicative feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Proper SQL

> I want to get 3 message groups in the below order: [1,2], [3,4], [5]

To get the requested order, add `ORDER BY min(id)`:

```sql
SELECT grp, user_id, array_agg(id) AS ids
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , user_id
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) -
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY 1   -- for ordered arrays in result
   ) t
GROUP  BY grp, user_id
ORDER  BY min(id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd8c4edce54865accb232deb5bc141d6)*
<sub>Old [sqliddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/345e1/1)</sub>

The addition would barely warrant another answer. The more important issue is this:

#### Faster with PL/pgSQL

> I'm using PostgreSQL and would be happy to use something specific to it, whatever would give the **best performance**.

Pure SQL is all nice and shiny, but a procedural **server-side function** is *much* faster for this task. While processing rows procedurally is *generally slower*, **plpgsql** wins this competition big-time, because it can make do with a *single* table scan and a *single* `ORDER BY` operation:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_msg_groups()
  RETURNS TABLE (ids int[])
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _id    int;
   _uid   int;
   _id0   int;                         -- id of last row
   _uid0  int;                         -- user_id of last row
BEGIN
   FOR _id, _uid IN
       SELECT id, user_id FROM messages ORDER BY id
   LOOP
       IF _uid <> _uid0 THEN
          RETURN QUERY VALUES (ids);   -- output row (never happens after 1 row)
          ids := ARRAY[_id];           -- start new array
       ELSE
          ids := ids || _id;           -- add to array
       END IF;

       _id0  := _id;
       _uid0 := _uid;                  -- remember last row
   END LOOP;

   RETURN QUERY VALUES (ids);          -- output last iteration
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_msg_groups();
```

#### Benchmark and links

I ran a quick test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on a similar real life table with 60k rows (execute several times, pick fastest result to exclude cashing effects):

SQL:
Total runtime: 1009.549 ms
Pl/pgSQL:
Total runtime: **336.971 ms**

Related:

- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values)
- [GROUP BY consecutive dates delimited by gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009893/group-by-consecutive-dates-delimited-by-gaps?lq=1)
- [Ordered count of consecutive repeats / duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078964/ordered-count-of-consecutive-repeats-duplicates)

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, array_agg(id)
FROM (
SELECT id, 
       user_id, 
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY created_at)-
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) conv_id
FROM table1 ) t
GROUP BY user_id, conv_id;
```

The expression:

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY created_at)-
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) conv_id
```

Will give you a special id for every message group (this `conv_id` can be repeated for other `user_id`, but `user_id, conv_id` will give you all distinct message groups)

My [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/82fe7/2) with example.

Details: [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html), [`OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` clause will collapse the response in 2 records - one with `user_id` 1 and one with `user_id` 2 no matter of the `ORDER BY` clause so I recommend you'd send just the `ORDER BY created_at`

```
prev_id = -1
messages.each do |m|
 if ! m.user_id == prev_id do 
    prev_id = m.user_id
    #do whatever you want with a new message group
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
Message = Struct.new :id, :user_id

messages = []
messages << Message.new(1, 1)
messages << Message.new(2, 1)
messages << Message.new(3, 2)
messages << Message.new(4, 2)
messages << Message.new(5, 1)

messages.chunk(&:user_id).each do |user_id, records| 
  p "#{user_id} - #{records.inspect}" 
end
```

The output:

```
"1 - [#<struct Message id=1, user_id=1>, #<struct Message id=2, user_id=1>]"
"2 - [#<struct Message id=3, user_id=2>, #<struct Message id=4, user_id=2>]"
"1 - [#<struct Message id=5, user_id=1>]"
```