# How to group following rows by not unique value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have data like this:

```
table1
_____________
id way time
1  1   00:01
2  1   00:02
3  2   00:03
4  2   00:04
5  2   00:05
6  3   00:06
7  3   00:07
8  1   00:08
9  1   00:09
```

I would like to know in which time interval I was on which way:

```
desired output
_________________
id  way from   to    
1   1   00:01  00:02
3   2   00:03  00:05
6   3   00:06  00:07
8   1   00:08  00:09
```

I tried to use a window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  first_value(id) OVER w AS id, 
  first_value(way) OVER w as way,
  first_value(time) OVER w as from,
  last_value(time) OVER w as to
FROM table1
WINDOW w AS (
  PARTITION BY way ORDER BY ID
  range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following);
```

What I get is:

```
ID  way from   to    
 1   1  00:01  00:09
 3   2  00:03  00:05
 6   3  00:06  00:07
```

And this is not correct, because on way 1 I wasn't from 00:01 to 00:09.
Is there a possibility to do the partition according to the order, means grouping only following attributes, that are equal?

Comment: How is `way` `2` `00:03 - 00:05` and `way` `3` `00:06-00:07` ? This is very confusing.

Comment: It was wrong, I fixed it. Thx.

Comment: You make it seem like `id` and `time` both would be strictly ascending in parallel. Is that so? Are you sure? If `id` is a `serial` column, that's most probably ***not*** always the case. This would mean that the minimum `id` and minimum `time` for one time slice could be in different rows. What should be in the result then?

Comment: No they are not. The id is strictly ascending in the order I drove through the ways. However the doesn't need to be unique, some ways have the same start and end time (end time is basically the start time of the next way, not shown in the example) and theoretically the start time of the following line could be before (and so the ending time).
I got the data from a mapmatch of GPS tracks to a Openstreetmap network. The ways are in the right order. However I assigned the timestamp to the edge by joining the nearest neighbor GPS point, which could leed to errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your case is as simple as the example values suggest, [@Giorgos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30878188/939860) serves nicely.

However, that's **typically not the case**. If the `id` column is a `serial`, you cannot rely on the assumption that a row with an earlier `time` also has a smaller `id`.
Also, `time` values (or `timestamp` like you probably have) can easily be duplicates, you need to make the sort order unambiguous.

Assuming both can happen, and you want the `id` from the row with the earliest `time` per time slice (actually, the *smallest* `id` for the earliest *time*, there could be ties), this query would deal with the situation properly:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (way, grp)
          id, way, time AS time_from
        , max(time) OVER (PARTITION BY way, grp) AS time_to
   FROM (
      SELECT *
           , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY time, id)  -- id as tie breaker
           - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY way ORDER BY time, id) AS grp
      FROM   table1
      ) t
   ORDER  BY way, grp, time, id
   ) sub
ORDER  BY time_from, id;
```

- `ORDER BY time, id` to be unambiguous. Assuming time is *not* unique, add the (assumed unique) `id` to avoid arbitrary results - that could change between queries in sneaky ways.
- `max(time) OVER (PARTITION BY way, grp)`: without `ORDER BY`, the window frame spans all rows of the PARTITION, so we get the absolute maximum per time slice.
- The outer query layer is only necessary to produce the desired sort order in the result, since we are bound to a different `ORDER BY` in the subquery `sub` by using `DISTINCT ON`. Details:

  - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1c8a1/1) demonstrating the use case.

If you are looking to optimize performance, a plpgsql function could be faster in such a case. Closely related answer:

- [Group by repeating attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010348/group-by-repeating-attribute/14016575#14016575)

Aside: don't use the basic type name `time` as identifier (also a [reserved word in standard SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
select min(id), way, 
       min(time), max(time)
from (
select id, way, time,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY way ORDER BY time) AS grp
from table1 ) t
group by way, grp
```

`grp` identifies 'islands' of *successive* `way` values. Using this calculated field in an outer query, we can get *start* and *end* times of `way` intervals using `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate functions respectively.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2fb69/7)

Comment: @Nassim The OP wants to identify islands of *successive* `way` values. There are **4** of them in the sample data posted. Please have a look at *desired output* and *not* at *what I get* output.

Comment: yes i misunderstood the question , so i deleted my answer, in that case your answer is more accurate +1