# Group consecutive rows based on one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Suppose I have this table from the result of a `select * from journeys`:

```
timestamp     | inJourney (1 = true and 0 = false)
--------------------------------------------------
time1         | 1
time2         | 1
time3         | 1
time4         | 0
time5         | 0
time6         | 1
time7         | 1
time8         | 1
```

Expected:

```
timestamp     | inJourney (1 = true and 0 = false)
--------------------------------------------------
time1         | 1
time4         | 0
time8         | 1
```

Note: the timestamp is not important because I only want to count the number of journeys.

Any idea what I have to do?

Comment: Same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880137/939860. Or this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/112846/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You're right. I didn't find that post. Thanks.

Comment: Once you know the search term "gaps and islands", it gets easier. But there are still many variants of the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Use the difference of `row_number()`:

```
select injourney, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by injourney, order by timestamp) as seqnum_i
      from t
     ) t
group by injourney, (seqnum - seqnum_i)
order by min(timestamp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't aware of this problem (gaps-and-islands problem) but now I know. I've been in this for hours. You deserve a fantastic weekend. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get the gap from result set then use `MIN`

You can try this.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT MIN(timestamp),inJourney 
FROM (
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp)  - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY inJourney ORDER BY timestamp) grp
  FROM journeys
) t1
GROUP BY grp,inJourney 
ORDER BY MIN(timestamp);

| min   | injourney |
| ----- | --------- |
| time1 | 1         |
| time4 | 0         |
| time6 | 1         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sCuF1YYpLR4uf86EaD94kK/0)