# Sql group query results by user id and date ranges dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group, generate-series

I have a query that collects information from different tables for a particular time range.

Currently, I make requests for every user and every date range separately, but I would like to run it for all time ranges at once, where the time range is every seven days between user_opened_account_at and user_closed_account_at, which is different for every user.

Is there any proper way to do this in one query?

Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aDFuX4qjzCcUmXe8iipaBM/2

The result I have:
[image: result I have]

The result I want to see:
[image: Result I want to see]

Query:

```sql
SELECT 
    usr.id as user_id,
    usr."onboardedAt" as user_opened_account_at,
    usr."closedAt" as user_closed_account_at,
    '2021-01-01' as start_range_date,
    '2021-01-08' as end_range_date,
    tx.tx_count as tx_count,
    last_user_action.action as last_user_action
FROM "Users" usr

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        "userId",
        COUNT("id") as "tx_count"
    FROM "Transactions"
    WHERE "createdAt" >= '2021-01-01' AND "createdAt" < '2021-01-08'
    GROUP BY "userId"
) tx ON usr.id = tx."userId"

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "userId", "action"
    FROM "UserActions"
    WHERE "createdAt" >= '2021-01-01' AND "createdAt" < '2021-01-08'
    ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) last_user_action ON usr.id = last_user_action."userId"

WHERE usr.id = 1
ORDER BY user_id, start_range_date
```

Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Users" (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    "onboardedAt" timestamp with time zone,
    "closedAt" timestamp with time zone
);

CREATE TABLE "Transactions" (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    "userId" bigint,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
    amount numeric(20,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE "UserActions" (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    "userId" bigint,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
    action character varying(255) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO "Users" ("onboardedAt", "closedAt") VALUES 
    ( '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01' ), 
    ( '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01' ), 
    ( '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01' ), 
    ( '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01' ), 
    ( '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01' );

INSERT INTO "Transactions" ("userId", "createdAt", "amount") VALUES 
    ( 1, '2021-01-02',  100 ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-08', -100 ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-15', -200 ),
    ( 1, '2021-01-22',  200 ),

    ( 2, '2021-01-02', -100 ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-02',  100 ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-15', -200 ),
    ( 2, '2021-01-16',  200 ), 

    ( 3, '2021-01-02',  100 ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-08', -100 ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-15', -200 ),
    ( 3, '2021-01-22',  200 ),

    ( 4, '2021-02-02',   50 ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-08', -100 ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-15', -200 ),
    ( 4, '2021-02-22',  200 ),

    ( 5, '2021-02-02',  200 ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-08', -400 ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-15', -600 ),
    ( 5, '2021-02-22',  200 );

INSERT INTO "UserActions" ("userId", "createdAt", "action") VALUES 
    ( 1, '2021-01-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-02', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-08', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-09', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-15', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 1, '2021-01-22', 'PLAY' ), 

    ( 2, '2021-01-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-02', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-08', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-09', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-15', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 2, '2021-01-22', 'PLAY' ), 

    ( 3, '2021-01-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-02', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-08', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-09', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-15', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 3, '2021-01-22', 'PLAY' ), 

    ( 4, '2021-02-01', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-02', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-08', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-09', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-15', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 4, '2021-02-22', 'PLAY' ), 

    ( 5, '2021-02-01', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-01', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-02', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-08', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-09', 'PLAY' ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-15', 'DEPOSIT' ), 
    ( 5, '2021-02-22', 'PLAY' );
```

Comment: Do you want your weeks to start on *Mondays*? Currently, it sounds like every user uses different weeks, depending on  their `"onboardedAt"` (which seems odd).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, it is just a 7 days interval that is different from user to user

Comment: Note that we very much prefer *text* over images for data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all weeks starting on Monday, this would do it (efficiently):

```sql
SELECT id AS user_id, u."onboardedAt", u."closedAt"
     , week_start, COALESCE(t.tx_count, 0) AS tx_count, a.last_user_action
FROM   "Users" u
CROSS  JOIN  generate_series(date_trunc('week', u."onboardedAt"), u."closedAt", interval '1 week') AS week_start
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT "userId" AS id, date_trunc('week', t."createdAt") AS week_start, count(*) AS tx_count
   FROM   "Transactions" t
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) t USING (id, week_start)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
          "userId" AS id, date_trunc('week', a."createdAt") AS week_start, action AS last_user_action
   FROM   "UserActions" a
   ORDER  BY 1, 2, "createdAt" DESC
   ) a USING (id, week_start)
ORDER  BY id, week_start;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1c6a9326dc377b0c6b7ff0945279f8f9)*

Working with standard weeks makes everything much simpler. We can aggregate in the "many" tables before joining, which is simpler and cheaper. Else, multiple joins can go wrong quickly. See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

Standard weeks make it easier to compare data, too. (Note that first and last week per user can be truncated (span fewer days). But that applies to the last week per user in any case.)

The `LATERAL` keyword is assumed automatically in a join to a set-returning *function*:

```
CROSS  JOIN  generate_series(...)
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Using `DISTINCT ON` to get the `last_user_action` per user. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

I advise to user legal, lower-case identifiers, so double-quoting is not required. Makes your life with Postgres easier.

#### Use last non-null action

Added in a comment:

> if action is null in a current week, I want to grab most recent from previous weeks

```sql
SELECT user_id, "onboardedAt", "closedAt", week_start, tx_count
     , last_user_action AS last_user_action_with_null
     , COALESCE(last_user_action, max(last_user_action) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, null_grp)) AS last_user_action
FROM  (
   SELECT id AS user_id, u."onboardedAt", u."closedAt"
        , week_start, COALESCE(t.tx_count, 0) AS tx_count, a.last_user_action
        , count(a.last_user_action) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY week_start) AS null_grp
   FROM   "Users" u
   CROSS  JOIN  generate_series(date_trunc('week', u."onboardedAt"), u."closedAt", interval '1 week') AS week_start
   LEFT   JOIN (
      SELECT "userId" AS id, date_trunc('week', t."createdAt") AS week_start, count(*) AS tx_count
      FROM   "Transactions" t
      GROUP  BY 1, 2
      ) t  USING (id, week_start)
   LEFT   JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
             "userId" AS id, date_trunc('week', a."createdAt") AS week_start, action AS last_user_action
      FROM   "UserActions" a
      ORDER  BY 1, 2, "createdAt" DESC
      ) a USING (id, week_start)
   ) sub
ORDER  BY user_id, week_start;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b38332d448a581e6385438f2fdd0c21c)*

Explanation:

- [Retrieve last known value for each column of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246242/retrieve-last-known-value-for-each-column-of-a-row/20253371#20253371)

Comment: One more following question, if action is null in a current week, I want to grab most recent from previous weeks.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifRQvK6ZFnpgf5tpSZLKqS/1

I used ranking by creation date, but it produces duplicates, so I district them in main select. I am wondering is there any other better/elegant solution?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You do have to use a [LATERAL join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) so that you can use the column values from your left table (Users) in the generate_series() table expression, but otherwise it's mostly what you'd expect. Some simplified SQL showing the important parts follows, please add a dbfiddle link with sample data if you'd like fully-working code.

```
SELECT u.user_id, week_start, count(t.transactions) tx_count
from users AS u
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(u.onboarded_at, u.account_closed_at, interval '1 week')
    AS week_start
LEFT JOIN transactions AS t
  ON t.created_at >= week_start AND
  AND t.created_at < (week_start + interval '1 week')
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Note that this is still mostly a glorified for-loop server-side, but that will almost always be significantly more performant than a for-loop in your code that roundtrips to the DB.

Comment: Thank you, changing my queries to check it.