# MySQL/Postgres query 5 minutes interval data

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need help with the query, let's say that this is the data in table.

```
timestamp           
------------------- 
2010-11-16 10:30:00
2010-11-16 10:37:00
2010-11-16 10:40:00 
2010-11-16 10:45:00
2010-11-16 10:48:00
2010-11-16 10:55:00
2010-11-16 10:56:00
```

I want to get every first row (timestamp) that is at least 5 minutes later than the last. In this case the query should return:

```
timestamp           
------------------- 
2010-11-16 10:30:00
2010-11-16 10:37:00
2010-11-16 10:45:00
2010-11-16 10:55:00
```

Comment: Is this Postgres or MySql?

Comment: I need it for postgres, but any suggestion is acceptable because i am completely out of ideas.

Comment: 5 minutes greater than the previous row in the source table, or 5 minutes greater than the last row in the result table? e.g. if you put an extra row on the end of the data at 11:00:00 do you expect it to be in the resultset?

Comment: 5 minutes greater than the last row in the result table, which means that 11:00:00 should be in the query results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Recursive CTE

Since each row depends on the one before, it is hard to solve with a set-based approach. Resorting to a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (which is standard SQL):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT ts FROM tbl
   ORDER BY ts
   LIMIT 1
   )

   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT t.ts
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   tbl t ON t.ts >= c.ts + interval '5 min'
   ORDER  BY t.ts
   LIMIT 1
   )
   )
TABLE cte ORDER BY ts;
```

Aggregate functions are not allowed in a recursive CTE. I substituted with `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT 1`, which is fast when supported by an **index** on `ts`.

The parentheses around each leg of the `UNION` query are necessary to allow `LIMIT`, which would otherwise only be permitted once at the end of a `UNION` query.

#### PL/pgSQL function

A procedural solution (example with a plpgsql function) iterating through the sorted table would probably be a lot faster, since it can make do with a single table scan:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_rowgrid(i interval)
  RETURNS SETOF timestamp
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _this  timestamp;
   _last  timestamp := '-infinity';     -- init so that 1 row passes
BEGIN
   FOR _this IN
       SELECT ts FROM tbl ORDER BY 1
   LOOP
       IF _this >= _last + i THEN
          RETURN NEXT _this;
          _last := _this;
       END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM  f_rowgrid('5 min');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=309823626d781bc0984529c794d0141b)* - demonstrating both
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8a555f/1)</sub>

Here is a more complex example for this type of plpgsql functions:

- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values/8014694#8014694)

Could easily be made generic with dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE` to work for arbitrary tables.

- [There are quite a few code examples here on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20execute%20regclass%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the recursive query is doing the work...I just now need to find the way to execute this query in PHP.