# SQL Query where I get most recent rows from timestamp from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, timestamp, plpgsql

I've got some sensory information going into a table. I have figured out the query that will tell me exactly when the value at a particular device changes.

What I need to know is the status of all of the other sensors at that time. The trick is, the timestamps won't be equal. I could get a data point from sensor 1, then 3 minute later, one from sensor 2, and then 30 seconds later, another from sensor 1.

So, here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
--- data_table ---

sensor | state | stime
-------+-------+---------------------
     1 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:42:00
     1 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:43:00
     2 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:44:00
     3 |     C | 2014-08-17 21:45:00
     2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00
     3 |     C | 2014-08-17 21:47:00
     1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00
     3 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:49:00
     2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:50:00
     2 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:51:00
```

Now, I know the query that will deliver me the state changes. I've got this down, and it's in a view. That table would look like:

```
 --- state_changed_view ---

sensor | state | stime
-------+-------+---------------------
     2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00
     1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00
     3 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:49:00
     2 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:51:00
```

What I want is a JOIN, where I can get all of the values of the 'state_changed_view', but also the values of the other corresponding sensors at the 'sensor_timestamp' within the view.

So, ideally, I want my result to look like (or something similar to):

```
sensor | state | stime               | sensor | state | stime
-------+-------+---------------------+--------+-------+---------------------
     2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00 |      1 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:43:00
     2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00 |      2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00
     2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00 |      3 |     C | 2014-08-17 21:45:00
     1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00 |      1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00
     1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00 |      2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00
     1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00 |      3 |     C | 2014-08-17 21:47:00
     3 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:49:00 |      1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00
     3 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:49:00 |      2 |     D | 2014-08-17 21:46:00 
     3 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:49:00 |      3 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:49:00 
     2 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:51:00 |      1 |     B | 2014-08-17 21:48:00 
     2 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:51:00 |      2 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:51:00 
     2 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:51:00 |      3 |     A | 2014-08-17 21:49:00
```

As you can see, I need the most recent row in 'data_table' for each sensor, for every row that exists in `state_changed_view`.

I just don't know how to get the SQL to get me the most recent row according to a particular timestamp.

This is on a PL/pgSQL system, so anything compatible with Postgres is handy.

Comment: `PL/SQL` is the procedural language of *Oracle*. What do you really mean?

Comment: Can we assume a unique constraint on `(sensor, stime)`? Is the number of sensors dynamic or do you know them at the time of asking?

Comment: I know the number ahead of time, so yeah, we can assume it is static.  And should've said PL/pgSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Query

For a **small**, **given** set of sensors to retrieve (this works for Postgres **8.4** or later):

```
SELECT c.sensor AS sensor_change
     , d1.state AS state_1, d1.stime AS stime_1
     , d2.state AS state_2, d2.stime AS stime_2
     , d3.state AS state_3, d3.stime AS stime_3
FROM  (
   SELECT sensor, stime
        , lag(state) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor ORDER BY stime)
           <> state AS change
        , max(CASE WHEN sensor = 1 THEN stime ELSE NULL END) OVER w AS last_1
        , max(CASE WHEN sensor = 2 THEN stime ELSE NULL END) OVER w AS last_2
        , max(CASE WHEN sensor = 3 THEN stime ELSE NULL END) OVER w AS last_3
   FROM   data d
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY stime)
   ) c
JOIN   data d1 ON d1.sensor = 1 AND d1.stime = c.last_1
JOIN   data d2 ON d2.sensor = 2 AND d2.stime = c.last_2
JOIN   data d3 ON d3.sensor = 3 AND d3.stime = c.last_3
WHERE  c.change
ORDER  BY c.stime;
```

Not using the view at all, building on the table directly, that's faster.

This is assuming a UNIQUE INDEX on `(sensor, stime)` to be unambiguous. Performance also heavily depends on such an index.

As opposed to [@Nick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25388757/939860), building on `JOIN LATERAL` (Postgres 9.3+), this returns a **single row** with all values for every change in state.

### PL/pgSQL function

Since you mentioned PL/pgSQL, I would expect this (highly optimized) plpgsql function to perform better, since it can make do with a single sequential scan of the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sensor_change()
  RETURNS TABLE (sensor_change int   -- adapt to actual data types!
               , state_1 "char", stime_1 timestamp
               , state_2 "char", stime_2 timestamp
               , state_3 "char", stime_3 timestamp) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r    data%rowtype;
BEGIN

FOR r IN
   TABLE data ORDER BY stime
LOOP
   CASE r.sensor
   WHEN 1 THEN  
      IF    r.state =  state_1 THEN  -- just save stime
         stime_1 := r.stime;
      ELSIF r.state <> state_1 THEN  -- save all & RETURN
         stime_1 := r.stime; state_1 := r.state;
         sensor_change := 1; RETURN NEXT;
      ELSE                           -- still NULL: init
         stime_1 := r.stime; state_1 := r.state;
      END IF;

   WHEN 2 THEN
      IF    r.state =  state_2 THEN
         stime_2 := r.stime;
      ELSIF r.state <> state_2 THEN
         stime_2 := r.stime; state_2 := r.state;
         sensor_change := 2; RETURN NEXT;
      ELSE
         stime_2 := r.stime; state_2 := r.state;
      END IF;

   WHEN 3 THEN
      IF    r.state =  state_3 THEN
         stime_3 := r.stime;
      ELSIF r.state <> state_3 THEN
         stime_3 := r.stime; state_3 := r.state;
         sensor_change := 3; RETURN NEXT;
      ELSE
         stime_3 := r.stime; state_3 := r.state;
      END IF;
   ELSE             -- do nothing, ignore other sensors
   END CASE;
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_sensor_change();
```

Makes sense for repeated use. Related answer:

- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values/8014694#8014694)

[**SQL Fiddle for Postgres 9.3.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e7c8/1)
[**SQL Fiddle for Postgres 8.4.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/4e7c8/1)

Comment: I have to tell you that this was absolutely impressive.  It works for my small number of sensors.  I know I need to upgrade Postgres (nearly every time I post on here, I get that remark), but that upgrade will be huge.  Fortunately, it is coming soon.  Thanks so much for your work.  This was fantastic.

Comment: @jasonmclose: Note the further simplification to the query. Plus, I added a plpgsql variant. I would be very interested which performs better in your case. Would you mind running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and leaving  a comment here with the results (best of 5 or something to rule out caching artifacts).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will try to get this in some time today or tomorrow.  I am in a time crunch at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things making this not-so-straightforward:

- You want to do a subquery for each `state_changed_view` row, but the subquery must mention the corresponding `stime` from the view (to restrict it to earlier records). Ordinary subqueries aren't allowed to depend on external fields, but you can accomplish this (as of Postgres 9.3, at least) with a [lateral join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL).
- You need not only `MAX(data_table.stime)`, but the corresponding `data_table.state`. You could do this with *another* nested query to retrieve the rest of the row, but [`SELECT DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html) gives you an easy way to fetch the whole thing at once.

The end result is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  state_changed_view,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (sensor)
      sensor,
      state,
      stime
    FROM
      data_table
    WHERE
      data_table.stime <= state_changed_view.stime
    ORDER BY
      sensor,
      stime DESC
  ) a
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, I must be running on 8.4, and cannot upgrade for business reasons.  This always seems to be an issue, where the answer to my question is always easily gained by a release that is yet to be supported for my system.

Comment: @jasonmclose: I've got a solution in 8.4 for you, but you really should consider upgrading. [8.4 has reached reaching EOL in July](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). I like this elegant solution, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the max time for each sensor and state with a subquery which groups on sensor and state and then join that to the view

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT sensor, state, MAX(stime) as stime
from data_table
group by sensor, state) a
join state_changed_view on 1=1
```

Comment: When I try this on my real data, it returns a lot more data than the mapping I would like.  It is close though.  Definitely more than I've got so far.