# Sliding 1-hour periods aggregation query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.2, recursive-query

In Postgres 9.2, I have a table containing measures taken at specific points in time:

```
CREATE TABLE measures (dt timestamptz, measure integer);

INSERT INTO measures VALUES
('2015-01-13 12:05', 10), 
('2015-01-13 12:30', 8), 
('2015-01-13 13:02', 16), 
('2015-01-13 13:30', 12), 
('2015-01-13 14:15', 7);
```

I want to calculate the average and count of lines for 1-hour periods, which I *can* do this way:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', dt) as d, max(measure), count(*)
FROM measures group by d order by d;
```

But instead of 1-hour periods starting at 12:00, 13:00 etc. I want 1-hour periods following an event. That's one period from **12:05 to 13:05** and the next from **13:30 to 14:30** in this case.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Interesting problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Recursive CTE

Plain SQL with a [**recursive CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) works:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT t.dt, m.measure
   FROM  (SELECT dt FROM measures ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1) t -- no lower bound
   JOIN   measures m ON m.dt < t.dt + interval '1h'  -- excl. upper bound

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.dt, m.measure
   FROM  (
      SELECT m.dt
      FROM  (SELECT dt FROM cte LIMIT 1) c
      JOIN   measures m ON m.dt >= c.dt + interval '1h'
      ORDER  BY 1
      LIMIT  1
      ) t
   JOIN   measures m ON m.dt >= t.dt                 -- incl. lower bound
                    AND m.dt <  t.dt + interval '1h' -- excl. upper bound
   )
SELECT dt AS hour_start
     , round(avg(measure), 2) AS avg_measure, count(*) AS ct
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Returns:

```
hour_start          | avg_measure | ct
--------------------+-------------+----
2015-01-13 13:05:00 | 11.33       | 3
2015-01-13 14:30:00 | 9.50        | 2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=01b242f48b9b60a6560db923b806e527)* (with added test on big table with index and selected time frame)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2bb27/1)</sub>

It performs decently with an index on `dt` - or better a [**multicolumn index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) to allow [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) in Postgres 9.2+:

```
CREATE INDEX measures_foo_idx ON measures (dt, measure);
```

That's standard SQL [including the recursive CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) except for `LIMIT`. Postgres supports the standard keywords [`FETCH FIRST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause) as well, if you need it all standard SQL.

### Window function?

#### Not possible with a single window function

While the result of a window function is an aggregate over the window frame, the frame definition itself cannot reference other rows. In your case, granularity is dynamically determined by considering *all* rows from first to last. This is not possible with a single window function.

#### But!

We can still get rolling hourly averages for *every row* using a [window frame with the **`RANGE` clause bounded by an interval**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) - requires **Postgres 11** or later.

```sql
SELECT *, avg(measure) OVER (ORDER BY dt
                             RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '1 hour' FOLLOWING)
FROM   measures;
```

That generates aggregates for every row cheaply. Then we need to filter every start of a new period dynamically. We can use the row count and skip ahead by the number of rows in each hourly period - a [**PL/pgSQL cursor**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) lends itself to the task naturally:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynamic_hourly_avg()
  RETURNS TABLE(hour_start timestamp, avg_measure numeric, ct int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _cursor CURSOR FOR
      SELECT dt, round(avg(measure) OVER w, 2), count(*) OVER w 
      FROM   measures
      WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '1 hour' FOLLOWING);
BEGIN
    OPEN _cursor;
    FETCH _cursor INTO hour_start, avg_measure, ct;
    WHILE FOUND
    LOOP
      RETURN NEXT;
      FETCH RELATIVE ct FROM _cursor INTO hour_start, avg_measure, ct;
    END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_dynamic_hourly_avg();
```

This turns out to be ***very efficient*** with only ***few*** rows per period. It will fall of with too ***many*** rows per period. Hard to pin down a number. Turns out to be **1000x faster** in a quick benchmark with < 10 rows per period each.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=01b242f48b9b60a6560db923b806e527)*

We could even work with a [dynamic cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#id-1.8.8.9.5.5) and pass table and columns names to make it work for any table ...

#### Optimize performance

You basically need to iterate over all rows, which can be faster with a procedural solution: a **`FOR` loop in a plpgsql function**. Which will be faster?

- The recursive query for *few hours* with *many rows each*.
- The function for *many hours* with *few rows each*.
- **Update:** the added function with a cursor over a query with window functions beats the rest by a long shot (while there are not too many rows per period?)

Related PL/pgSQL solutions:

- [Group by repeating attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010348/group-by-repeating-attribute/14016575#14016575)
- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values/8015107#8015107)
- [SQL Query where I get most recent rows from timestamp from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387548/sql-query-where-i-get-most-recent-rows-from-timestamp-from-another-table/25390980#25390980)

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer, I was not familiar with the recursive CTE.

Comment: @zen: Consider the update. Improved the query a bit and added a fiddle.

Comment: wow, the query is indeed improved : in my test table it took 160s and now takes 180ms. Thanks a lot for the followup.

Comment: @zen: Factor 1000. That's what I like to hear. :) I am pretty sure, a plpgsql function could be faster, still.

Comment: @zen: The question is old, but I arrived at a much better solution in a related case. You might be interested in the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a function is postgresql that adds an hour to a datetime then you should be able to join  your result set on itself based on the date and date + 1 hour in an inner query then aggergate the values up in an outer query to get the results you need.

```
SELECT
    LowDate,
    HighDate=DATEADD(HOUR,1,LowDate),
    SumMeasure=SUM(measure),
    ItemCount=COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        LowDate=M1.dt,  
        measure=M2.measure
    FROM
        measures M1 
        INNER JOIN measures M2 ON M2.dt BETWEEN M1.dt AND DATEADD(HOUR,1,M1.dt)
)AS DETAIL  
GROUP BY
    LowDate 
ORDER BY
    LowDate
```

Comment: This is helpful but outputs five lines : one for each input line.
What I aim to do is outputing only two lines, one for 12:05 and one for 13:30, as the other events are contained into these
Postgres code of your function for reference:
`SELECT
    LowDate,
    LowDate + '1 hour' as HighDate, 
    SUM(measure) as SumMeasure,
   COUNT(*) as  ItemCount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        M1.dt as LowDate,  
        M2.measure as measure
    FROM
        measures M1 
        INNER JOIN measures M2 ON M2.dt BETWEEN M1.dt AND M1.dt + '1 hour'
)AS DETAIL  
GROUP BY
    LowDate 
ORDER BY
    LowDate`

Comment: I see. I understand. hmmm. The structure you are pulling data from does not lend itself to a nice set based operation for the output you desire. It is likely impossible using standard sql. I would look into possible postgresql windowing functions. Other than that you may have to script it out using temp storage.

Comment: @zen: Please ***edit*** your question to clarify your requirements. Comments are hardly visible to the general public.

Comment: @lrb: A (non-trivial) recursive CTE can do the trick. I added an answer.