# Apache Spark find first different preceding row in Dataframe

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have an Apache Spark Dataframe of the following format

```
| ID |  groupId  | phaseName |
|----|-----------|-----------|
| 10 | someHash1 | PhaseA    |
| 11 | someHash1 | PhaseB    |
| 12 | someHash1 | PhaseB    |
| 13 | someHash2 | PhaseX    |
| 14 | someHash2 | PhaseY    |
```

Each row represents a phase that happens in a procedure that consists of several of these phases. The `ID` column represents a sequential order of phases and the `groupId` column shows which phases belong together.

I want to add a new column to the dataframe: previousPhaseName. This column should indicate the **previous different phase from the same procedure**. The first phase of a process (the one with the minimum ID) will have `null` as previous phase. When a phase occurs twice or more, the second (third...) occurrence will have the same previousPhaseName For example:

```
df = 
| ID |  groupId  | phaseName | prevPhaseName |
|----|-----------|-----------|---------------|
| 10 | someHash1 | PhaseA    | null          |
| 11 | someHash1 | PhaseB    | PhaseA        |
| 12 | someHash1 | PhaseB    | PhaseA        |
| 13 | someHash2 | PhaseX    | null          |
| 14 | someHash2 | PhaseY    | PhaseX        |
```

I am not sure how to implement this. My first approach would be:

- create a second empty dataframe df2
- for each row in df:
  find the row with groupId = row.groupId, ID < row.ID, and maximum id
- add this row to df2
- join df1 and df2

### Partial Solution using Window Functions

I used `Window Functions`to aggregate the Name of the previous phase, the number of previous occurrences (not necessarily in a row) of the current phase in the group and the information whether the current and previous phase names are equal:

```
WindowSpec windowSpecPrev = Window
  .partitionBy(df.col("groupId"))
  .orderBy(df.col("ID"));
WindowSpec windowSpecCount = Window
  .partitionBy(df.col("groupId"), df.col("phaseName"))
  .orderBy(df.col("ID"))
  .rowsBetween(Long.MIN_VALUE, 0);

df
  .withColumn("prevPhase", functions.lag("phaseName", 1).over(windowSpecPrev))
  .withColumn("phaseCount", functions.count("phaseId").over(windowSpecCount))
  .withColumn("prevSame", when(col("prevPhase").equalTo(col("phaseName")),1).otherwise(0))

df = 
| ID |  groupId  | phaseName | prevPhase   | phaseCount | prevSame |
|----|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------|----------|
| 10 | someHash1 | PhaseA    | null        |  1         |  0       |
| 11 | someHash1 | PhaseB    | PhaseA      |  1         |  0       |
| 12 | someHash1 | PhaseB    | PhaseB      |  2         |  1       |
| 13 | someHash2 | PhaseX    | null        |  1         |  0       |
| 14 | someHash2 | PhaseY    | PhaseX      |  1         |  0       |
```

**This is still not what I wanted to achieve but good enough for now**

### Further Ideas

To get the the name of the previous distinct phase I see three possibilities that I have not investigated thoroughly:

- Implement an own `lag`function that does not take an offset but recursively checks the previous line until it finds a value that is different from the given line. (Though I don't think it's possible to use own analytic window functions in Spark SQL)
- Find a way to dynamically set the offset of the `lag` function according to the value of `phaseCount`. (That may fail if the previous occurrences of the same phaseName do not appear in a single sequence)
- Use a `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` over the window that stores the ID and phaseName of the first given input and seeks for the highest ID with different phaseName.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in the following way:

1. Get the (ordinary) previous phase.
2. Introduce a new id that groups phases that occur in sequential order. (With help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values)). This takes two steps. First checking whether the current and previous phase names are equal and assigning a groupCount value accordingly. Second computing a cumulative sum over this value.
3. Assign the previous phase of the first row of a sequential group to all its members.

### Implementation

```
WindowSpec specGroup = Window.partitionBy(col("groupId"))  
                             .orderBy(col("ID"));
WindowSpec specSeqGroupId = Window.partitionBy(col("groupId")) 
                                  .orderBy(col("ID"))
                                  .rowsBetween(Long.MIN_VALUE, 0);
WindowSpec specPrevDiff = Window.partitionBy(col("groupId"), col("seqGroupId"))
                                .orderBy(col("ID"))
                                .rowsBetween(Long.MIN_VALUE, 0);

df.withColumn("prevPhase", coalesce(lag("phaseName", 1).over(specGroup), lit("NO_PREV"))) 
  .withColumn("seqCount", when(col("prevPhase").equalTo(col("phaseName")).or(col("prevPhase").equalTo("NO_PREV")),0).otherwise(1))
  .withColumn("seqGroupId", sum("seqCount").over(specSeqGroupId))
  .withColumn("prevDiff", first("prevPhase").over(specPrevDiff));
```

### Result

```
df = 
| ID |  groupId  | phaseName | prevPhase | seqCount | seqGroupId | prevDiff |
|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|----------|------------|----------|
| 10 | someHash1 | PhaseA    | NO_PREV   |  0       |  0         | NO_PREV  |
| 11 | someHash1 | PhaseB    | PhaseA    |  1       |  1         | PhaseA   |
| 12 | someHash1 | PhaseB    | PhaseA    |  0       |  1         | PhaseA   |
| 13 | someHash2 | PhaseX    | NO_PREV   |  0       |  0         | NO_PREV  |
| 14 | someHash2 | PhaseY    | PhaseX    |  1       |  1         | PhaseX   |
```

Any suggestions, specially in terms of efficiency of these operations are appreciated.

Comment: I could not find another way to approach this, did you ever find a better way? thanks btw, very clever on getting the FIRST(prev..) of whenever the change happens

Comment: unfotunately I did not look further into it, cool that it helped you though

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use Spark window (row frame) functions. Check the api documentation and the following post.

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I haven't solved the problem yet but it definitely pushed me in the right direction.