# How to number consecutive records per island?

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which looks like:

```
group    date        color
  A      1-1-2019      R
  A      1-2-2019      Y
  B      1-1-2019      R
  B      1-2-2019      Y
  B      1-3-2019      Y
  B      1-4-2019      R
  B      1-5-2019      R
  B      1-6-2019      R
```

And it's ordered by group and date. I want an extra column showing sequential number of **consecutive** color 'R' for each group.

**Required output:**

```
group    date        color    rank
  A      1-1-2019      R      1
  A      1-2-2019      Y      null
  B      1-1-2019      R      1
  B      1-2-2019      Y      null
  B      1-3-2019      Y      null
  B      1-4-2019      R      1
  B      1-5-2019      R      2
  B      1-6-2019      R      3
```

I've tried to use window function with partition by group and color columns but it returns output below which is not correct.

**Wrong Query and Output:**

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY group, color order by group, date) as rank
FROM table

group    date        color    rank
  A      1-1-2019      R      1
  A      1-2-2019      Y      null
  B      1-1-2019      R      1
  B      1-2-2019      Y      null
  B      1-3-2019      Y      null
  B      1-4-2019      R      2
  B      1-5-2019      R      3
  B      1-6-2019      R      4
```

I'm wondering if it's doable in SQL, or should I switch to another language (like Python)?

Comment: Are you using postgres (Microsoft SQL Server) or mysql? You tagged mysql but your sql looks like postgres

Comment: I'm using presto, but any database solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And you only want numbers for `R`, not `Y` or any other color? And can there be *any* duplicates? If so, how to handle those?

Comment: @RannieXue . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really usig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it can be done using window functions. First we create a CTE which has a flag which indicates that a new sequence has started, then from that we generate one which counts sequence numbers. Finally we count rows within each sequence to get the rank:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT `group`, date, color,
                    COALESCE(color = LAG(color) OVER(ORDER BY `group`, date), 0) AS samecolor
             FROM `table`),
sequences AS (SELECT `group`, date, color,
              SUM(samecolor = 0) OVER (ORDER BY `group`, date) AS seq_num
              FROM cte)
SELECT `group`, date, color,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq_num) AS `rank`
FROM sequences
ORDER BY `group`, date
```

Output:

```
group   date        color   rank
A       1-1-2019    R       1
A       1-2-2019    Y       1
B       1-1-2019    R       1
B       1-2-2019    Y       1
B       1-3-2019    Y       2
B       1-4-2019    R       1
B       1-5-2019    R       2
B       1-6-2019    R       3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/if3koQHjjo1iNNgBUZRtWK/2)

Note that this query also gives ranking for `Y` values, if you want those to be `NULL` replace the definition of `rank` with this:

```
CASE WHEN color = 'Y' THEN NULL
     ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq_num) 
     END AS `rank`
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using user variables could keep the rank and previous values to produce the results:

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl (
   `group` VARCHAR(1),
   `date` VARCHAR(8),
   `color` VARCHAR(1)
 );

 INSERT INTO tbl
   (`group`, `date`, `color`)
 VALUES
   ('A', '1-1-2019', 'R'),
   ('A', '1-2-2019', 'Y'),
   ('B', '1-1-2019', 'R'),
   ('B', '1-2-2019', 'Y'),
   ('B', '1-3-2019', 'Y'),
   ('B', '1-4-2019', 'R'),
   ('B', '1-5-2019', 'R'),
   ('B', '1-6-2019', 'R');

 set @seq := 0, @prev := 'B'

 SELECT 
     *, 
     IF(color='R', @seq := IF(@prev = color, @seq + 1, 1), NULL) AS rank,
     @prev := color as prev
 FROM tbl
 ORDER BY `group`, `date`
```

---

```
group | date     | color | rank | prev
:---- | :------- | :---- | ---: | :---
A     | 1-1-2019 | R     |    1 | R   
A     | 1-2-2019 | Y     |      | Y   
B     | 1-1-2019 | R     |    1 | R   
B     | 1-2-2019 | Y     |      | Y   
B     | 1-3-2019 | Y     |      | Y   
B     | 1-4-2019 | R     |    1 | R   
B     | 1-5-2019 | R     |    2 | R   
B     | 1-6-2019 | R     |    3 | R
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=dabfb8df97c43bb0a8f423079cd8e373)*

Comment: PS. Hope you use a `DATE` type rather than a varchar like I have here. Not important for this question however start to order/select it in anyway specified way and you'll have troubles.

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [window function **`row_number()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) for a pure standard SQL solution in **Postgres** - or any modern RDBMS, even MySQL since version 8:

```
SELECT grp, the_date, color
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp, color, part
                          ORDER BY the_date) AS rnk
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY the_date, color)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp, color ORDER BY the_date) AS part
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
ORDER BY grp, the_date, color;
```

This assumes that the combination `(grp, color, the_date)` is defined `UNIQUE`, duplicates would create non-deterministic results.

Substracting the two different row numbers computes a distinct number per island (`part`). Then you can run `row_number()` once more, now partitioning by the subgroup additionally. Voilá.

To only see numbers for a particular color, 'R' in the example:

```
SELECT grp, the_date, color, CASE WHEN color = 'R' THEN rnk END AS rnk
FROM  (
   <<query from above, without ORDER BY>>
   ) sub
ORDER  BY grp, the_date, color;
```

While set-based solution are the forté of RDBMS' and typically faster, a **procedural solution** only needs a single scan for this type of problem, so this plpgsql function should be substantially ***faster***:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rank_color(_color text = 'R')  -- default 'R'
  RETURNS TABLE (grp text, the_date date, color text, rnk int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _last_grp text;
BEGIN
   FOR grp, the_date, color IN
      SELECT t.grp, t.the_date, t.color FROM tbl t ORDER BY 1,2
   LOOP
      IF color = $1 THEN
         IF _last_grp = grp THEN
            rnk := COALESCE(rnk + 1, 1);
         ELSE
            rnk := 1;
         END IF;
      ELSIF rnk > 0 THEN  -- minimize assignments
         rnk := NULL;
      END IF;

      RETURN NEXT;
      _last_grp := grp;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM rank_color('R');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2a2719d3c3dca7d4e987ffae1331fd18)*

*Looping is **not always** the wrong solution in a relational database.*

Further reading:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)
- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values)

Aside: "rank" is a rather misleading name for those row numbers, unless you have duplicates supposed to rank equally ...