# Time series with running sum of latest orders per tenant

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

I've a Postgres table like this where a order count for each tenant is inserted when it changes.

| datetime | tenant_id | orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-15 22:00 | tenant3 | 2 |
| 2023-09-16 01:00 | tenant1 | 2 |
| 2023-09-16 02:00 | tenant1 | 3 |
| 2023-09-16 02:00 | tenant2 | 5 |
| 2023-09-16 03:00 | tenant1 | 4 |

Note that the first row for *tenant3* is from yesterday. The number of tenants is dynamic.

Is it possible, based on this data, to build a "time series"-like result where I sum of the newest *orders* count for all tenant, in a result like this:

| datetime | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-16 00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-09-16 01:00 | 4 |
| 2023-09-16 02:00 | 10 |
| 2023-09-16 03:00 | 11 |
| 2023-09-16 04:00 | 11 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-09-16 23:00 | ... |

Comment: It is not clear from the description how the example source data is to be transformed to the achive the output. You describe summing for **each** tenant; however, the output doesn't have a tenant column which seems like the sums are for **all** tenants. Exactly how do the sums relate to the input data?

Comment: @JohnH Sorry, I've tried to update the description. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dt AS datetime, sum(orders)
FROM (SELECT dt, max(datetime) AS datetime, tenant_id
      FROM generate_series(CURRENT_DATE::timestamp, CURRENT_DATE::timestamp + interval '23 hours', '1 hour') gs(dt)
      LEFT JOIN your_table t ON (t.datetime <= gs.dt)
      GROUP BY 1, 3) x
JOIN (SELECT datetime, tenant_id, orders FROM your_table) y USING (datetime, tenant_id)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Subquery `x` generates the time series consisting of all hours of the current day and then joins that to all the rows in your table that are earlier in time (`t.datetime <= gs.dt`) and then finds the most recent row for each combination of `tenant_id` and the time series period. In subquery `y` the `orders` for each combination of most recent `datetime` and `tenant_id` are found. In the main query the two subqueries are joined and then the sum of the `orders` is calculated.

This produces exactly the result you were asking for, but I had to assume a couple of things, such as that you wanted output for 24 hours of the current day. If you want to change that you should tweak the `generate_series()` call. You can also further restrict the join condition in subquery `x` to only count orders from the current month or whatever meets your need.

Comment: Why a left join using a subquery?

Comment: Because there may be hours when no orders are made.

Comment: And that’s why you need a subquery? To my knowledge a simple left join would be good enough, without the subquery

Comment: @FrankHeikens If you think the query can be optimized even further, could you please give an answer?

Comment: @dhrm: I added an optimized version of this query to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT to_char(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS today_hour  -- optional pretty print
     , sum(hour_sum) OVER (ORDER BY GREATEST(datetime, '2023-09-16 00:00')) AS sum
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2023-09-16'        -- CURRENT_DATE::timestamp
                     , timestamp '2023-09-16 23:00'  -- CURRENT_DATE::timestamp + interval '23 hours'
                     , interval  '1 hour') AS g(datetime)
LEFT   JOIN (      
   SELECT GREATEST(datetime, '2023-09-16 00:00') AS datetime  -- CURRENT_DATE
        , sum(delta) AS hour_sum
   FROM  (
      SELECT datetime
           , orders - lag(orders, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id ORDER BY datetime) AS delta
      FROM   tbl
      ) sub1
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub2 USING (datetime)
ORDER  BY datetime;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rdb7nrwB)

In your daily query, replace the date / timestamp literals with the commented expressions.

###### Step 1: subquery `sub1`

Get the delta of `orders` for each tenant between the current row and the previous one (if any). The window function call `lag(orders, 1, 0)` is instrumental for this. See:

- [Find all rows in between a set in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312219/find-all-rows-in-between-a-set-in-postgresql/58314630#58314630)

###### Step 2: subquery `sub2` / time-series `g`

Aggregate `delta` values per hour, starting with today 00:00 in `sub2`.
In parallel, generate one row for every full hour of the day in `g`. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

###### Step 3

`LEFT JOIN` to preserve exactly one output row per hour, then compute a running sum with the window function `sum(hour_sum)`

#### Alternative query for comparison

The idea behind [Patrick's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77117360/939860) can be implemented more efficiently with `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT datetime, sum(orders)
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (g.datetime, tenant_id)
          g.datetime, orders
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2023-09-16', timestamp '2023-09-16 23:00', '1 hour') g(datetime)
   LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.datetime <= g.datetime
   ORDER  BY g.datetime, tenant_id, t.datetime DESC NULLS LAST
   ) x
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Much simpler and faster. But not as fast as my first query, which scales much better for more tenants and/or more entries per tenant.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SZAfpRY7)

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH d AS (
  SELECT distinct datetime FROM mytable
)
SELECT
  d.datetime,
  d1.orders as "tenant1",
  d2.orders as "tenant2",
  d3.orders as "tenant3",
  d4.orders as "tenant4",
  COALESCE(d1.orders,0) + COALESCE(d2.orders,0) + COALESCE(d3.orders,0) + COALESCE(d4.orders,0) as "sum"
FROM d
LEFT JOIN mytable d1 on d1.datetime = d.datetime AND d1.tenant_id = 'tenant1'
LEFT JOIN mytable d2 on d2.datetime = d.datetime AND d2.tenant_id = 'tenant2'
LEFT JOIN mytable d3 on d3.datetime = d.datetime AND d3.tenant_id = 'tenant3'
LEFT JOIN mytable d4 on d4.datetime = d.datetime AND d4.tenant_id = 'tenant4'
ORDER BY d.datetime
```

output:

| datetime | tenant1 | tenant2 | tenant3 | tenant4 | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-15 22:00:00 | null | null | 2 | null | 2 |
| 2023-09-16 01:00:00 | 2 | null | null | null | 2 |
| 2023-09-16 02:00:00 | 3 | 5 | null | null | 8 |
| 2023-09-16 03:00:00 | 4 | null | null | null | 4 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/OaaErWpU)

**EDIT**: Because there are a dynamic number of tenants.

```
WITH d AS (
  SELECT distinct datetime from mytable
),
t as (
  select distinct tenant_id from mytable
)
SELECT
  datetime,
  SUM(orders)
FROM (
  SELECT
    d.datetime,
    t.tenant_id,
    m1.orders
  FROM d
  CROSS JOIN  t
  LEFT JOIN mytable m1 on m1.datetime = d.datetime and m1.tenant_id = t.tenant_id
) x
GROUP BY datetime
ORDER BY datetime
```

output:

| datetime | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-15 22:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-09-16 01:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-09-16 02:00:00 | 8 |
| 2023-09-16 03:00:00 | 4 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ypABczl0)

**EDIT2**: just for fun, as bonus:

adding `'(' || STRING_AGG(orders::varchar,'+' ORDER BY tenant_id ASC) || ')' as bonus`

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/VAPo_rlZ)

**EDIT3**: added `ORDER BY tenant_id ASC` to `STRING_AGG()` to make sure the calculation is in the order of tenants that take part in the sum.

will result in:

| datetime | sum | bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-15 22:00:00 | 2 | (2) |
| 2023-09-16 01:00:00 | 2 | (2) |
| 2023-09-16 02:00:00 | 8 | (3+5) |
| 2023-09-16 03:00:00 | 4 | (4) |

Comment: Sorry, but the number of tenants is dynamic :-( I've updated the description.

Answer (score -3):

```
Select datetime, sum(orders) 
From your_table
Group by datetime
Order by 1;
```

If you also want to include dates without orders, there are a few ways to do this. The way that will work on any rbdms is to join to a utility table that consists only of one column with one row per integer, starting from zero.

```
Select dateadd(day, b.value, (select min(datetime) from your_table)), sum(orders)
From your_table a 
right outer join utility b 
on ( a.datetime = dateadd(day, b.value, (select min(datetime) from your_table)))
Group by dateadd(day, b.value, (select min(datetime) from your_table))
Order by 1;
```

To create utility:

```
 Create table utility (value int not null);

 Insert into utility values (0);

 Insert into utility 
 select value + 1 +(select max(value) from utility) 
 from utility;
```

And repeat the last line until utility has enough records to cover all the days you need.