# Calculate Average Daily Uptime based on Status

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I have a table that tracks when a system is up or down. There are three columns: `interval_date` with datatype `DATE`, `interval_time_utc` with datatype `VARCHAR`, and `status` with datatype `INTEGER`. A status of 0 is up and 1 is down. I am trying to calculate the average uptime on a daily basis. Below is a table example.

| interval_date | interval_time_utc | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-08 | 04:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-07 | 20:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-07 | 04:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-06 | 17:45 | 1 |
| 2022-07-06 | 01:15 | 0 |
| 2022-07-05 | 18:40 | 1 |

So based on the data below:
System was up from 2022-07-05 00:00 to 2022-07-05 18:39 then down from 2022-07-05 18:40 to 2022-07-05 23:59.
System was down from 2022-07-06 00:00 to 2022-07-06 01:14 then the system was up from 2022-07-06 01:15 to 2022-07-06 17:44 then the system was down from 2022-07-06 17:45 to 2022-07-06 23:59.
System was down from 2022-07-07 00:00 to 2022-07-07 03:59 then the system was up from 2022-07-07 04:00 to 2022-07-07 19:59 then the system was down from 2022-07-07 20:00 to 2022-07-07 23:59.
System was down from 2022-07-08 00:00 to 2022-07-08 03:59 then the system was up from 2022-07-08 04:00 to the current UTC time.

Link to fiddle containing schema: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v7RCBBNowhv7DmfBoor64X/0

I would expect the following results (assuming my calculations are correct):

| interval_date | average_uptime |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 | 0.78 |
| 2022-07-06 | 0.69 |
| 2022-07-07 | 0.69 |
| 2022-07-08 | 0.83 |

Comment: `interval_date date, interval_time_utc varchar`? Looks like a broken table design if I have ever seen one. Just use one `timtestamp` or (typically better) `timestamptz` instead. Either way, instead of stories around your table definition, just provide a `CREATE TABLE` script, that's the canonical, unambiguous source of truth. And always declare your version of Postgres (`SELECT version();`)

Comment: You claim *"System was up from 2022-07-05 00:00 to 2022-07-05 18:39"* But that's not in the data. You claim that out of human reasoning - which is absent in the database server. You need to define explicitly, where your range of days in the result is supposed to start and end, whether each status must be the opposite of the previous, and what to assume about open lower and upper bounds. And is there at least one entry for each day, or can there be none?

Comment: The output shown for date 2022-07-07 is not correct. Up-time is 16 hrs (minus 1 min) i.e round to 0.67 daily avg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

- A current version of Postgres.
- A `UNIQUE` constraint on the timestamp.
- The leading fraction of the first day that is not covered by actual entry is the opposite status of the first entry.
- Other than that, every row is allowed to switch on or off (redundantly).
- The result shall contain all days between the first and last entry - including days without any change (all up or all down).

And I converted the table to a sane schema before working with it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fixed AS
SELECT interval_date + interval_time_utc::time AS interval_ts_utc, NOT status::bool AS up
FROM   system_power_history;
```

Then this does the job:

```sql
SELECT the_day, round(extract('epoch' FROM sum(uptime)) / 86400, 2) AS avg_uptime
FROM  (
   -- add start interval for 1st day (if up)
   SELECT interval_ts_utc::date AS the_day, interval_ts_utc::time::interval AS uptime
   FROM  (SELECT * FROM fixed ORDER BY interval_ts_utc LIMIT 1) sub
   WHERE  NOT up

   UNION ALL
   SELECT the_day, upper(range) - lower(range) AS uptime
   FROM  (
      SELECT the_day::date
           , tsrange(the_day, the_day + interval '1 day') * tsrange(ts, next_ts) AS range  -- intersect with day
      FROM  (
         SELECT interval_ts_utc AS ts
              , lead(interval_ts_utc, 1, date_trunc('day', interval_ts_utc) + interval '1 day')  -- default to start of next day
                     OVER (ORDER BY interval_ts_utc) AS next_ts
              , up
         FROM   fixed
         ) sub
      CROSS  JOIN LATERAL generate_series(date_trunc('day', ts)
                                        , next_ts - interval '1 us'
                                        , interval '1 day') the_day  -- get 1 row per intersecting day
      WHERE  up
      ) sub
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=759eaf9809b3ff745a71400dab06bd8e)*

Using the [range intersection operator **`*`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) for convenience.

**Except** that days with no uptime at all are missing in the result. Could be amended, but rather consider the next solution.

#### Procedural solution

The nature of the problem lends itself to a procedural solution. So this is one of the rare cases where a loop over the set **beats the performance** of a set-based solution:

Create function once:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_daily_uptimes()
  RETURNS TABLE (the_day date, uptime interval)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ts   timestamp;
   _ts0  timestamp;
   _up   bool;
   _up0  bool;
BEGIN
   FOR _ts, _up IN
      SELECT interval_ts_utc, up FROM fixed ORDER BY interval_ts_utc
   LOOP
      -- only for 1st iteration
      IF the_day IS NULL THEN
         the_day := _ts::date;
         _ts0 := the_day;
         _up0 = NOT _up;
      END IF;

      LOOP
         IF _up0 THEN
            uptime := LEAST(_ts, the_day + 1) - GREATEST(_ts0, the_day);
            RETURN NEXT;
         ELSIF the_day > _ts0::date AND _ts::date > the_day THEN  -- empty days
            uptime := '0:0';
            RETURN NEXT;
         END IF;

         EXIT WHEN the_day >= _ts::date;
         the_day = the_day + 1;
      END LOOP;
      
      _ts0 := _ts;  -- remember last row
      _up0 := _up;  -- remember last row
   END LOOP;

   -- final interval
   IF _up THEN
      uptime := (the_day + 1) - _ts0;
      RETURN NEXT;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```sql
SELECT the_day, round(extract('epoch' FROM sum(uptime)) / 86400, 2) AS avg_uptime
FROM   f_daily_uptimes()
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=759eaf9809b3ff745a71400dab06bd8e)*

Also includes days with no uptime at all - which are yet missing in my pure-SQL solution above.

Related:

- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values/8014694#8014694)

Comment: Hats off to Erwin Brandstetter!  I'm still getting my head around the range intersection, but that is such a useful feature I hadn't seen used before, especially with the lateral join.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell: Despite the relative elegance, this is still one of the rare cases where a procedural solution will be faster. I added one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it - get daily down-time and subtract from 24 hours, except for today, where the subtraction is from current utc time.

```
select interval_date, 
case when interval_date = current_date then 
round(cast((case when sum(int_time) < 0 then trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_time at time zone 'utc')/60 ) - sum(int_time)
else sum(int_time) end)/trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_time at time zone 'utc')/60 ) as numeric), 2) 
else
round(cast((case when sum(int_time) < 0 then 1440 + sum(int_time)
else sum(int_time) end)/1440 as numeric), 2) 
end up_time
from 
(
select interval_date, interval_time_utc,
case when status = 0 then (-1) * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval_time_utc::time)/60 
else EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval_time_utc::time)/60 - 1 end int_time,
status
from system_power_history
  ) t
  group by interval_date
  order by interval_date;
```

Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMqVUPaWVmrhe6qVUkejgr/1).